What is the Ruby equivalent of Python Dataclasses?
What is the counterpart for the Python Dataclass exist in Ruby?
In Python it is possible to use dataclasses to tersely define a class without explicitly defining an initialiser / __init__ method for it.
Without dataclasses this would look like this in Python (including arg typing):
class myNewDog2:
    def __init__(fur_colour: str, weight: float, is_microchipped: bool, is_asleep:bool=False):      
      self.fur_colour = fur_colour
      self.weight = weight
      self.is_microchipped = is_microchipped
      self.is_asleep = is_asleep
   
my_dog = myDog("tri-colour", 19.52, True)

But can be reduced to a form not requiring writing args out twice, using dataclasses:
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class myDog2:
    fur_colour: str
    weight: float
    is_microchipped: bool
    is_asleep: bool = False # Optional arg / defaults to False
   
my_dog = myDog("tri-colour", 19.52, True)

This is how an equivalent class definition looks like in Ruby:
class MyDog
  def initialize(fur_colour:, weight:, is_microchipped:, is_asleep: false)
    @fur_colour = fur_colour
    @weight = weight
    @is_microchipped = is_microchipped
    @is_asleep = is_asleep
  end 
end

How would I define this class in Ruby just as tersely as in Python? Is it possible to tell Ruby to fill in the blanks on the constructor based on only on a definition of the attributes I want the class to accept and maintain?

I guess you are looking for Ruby‘s Data class: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Data.html

Haha, a literal class Data - yes, that's what I was looking for but seem to have missed. Thanks

what's the different between Ruby Data vs Struct ?

A similar way in Ruby seems to be the Data class, which allows you to define simple value object like this:
MyDog = Data.define(:fur_colour, :weight, :is_microchipped, :is_asleep)

And you can create instances with positional or keyword arguments like this:
my_dog = MyDog.new('tri-colour', 19.52, true, false) # or
my_dog = MyDog.new(fur_colour: 'tri-colour', weight: 19.52, is_microchipped: true, is_asleep: false)

Please note that the Data class doesn't support optional arguments, like the is_asleep argument in your example, yet (tested this with Ruby 3.3.1). You always need to provide the same number of arguments as defined.

The general problem

What is the Ruby equivalent of Python Dataclasses?
What is the counterpart for the Python Dataclass exist in Ruby?

There is no such thing.
This is not just true for data classes and not just true for Python and Ruby. This is true for pretty much any feature X and pair of languages A and B.
Every language is different, so there will almost always be subtle differences and there will almost never be a full equivalent or counterpart in another language.
Rather than asking what the equivalent of feature X is, you should explain what the actual underlying problem is you are trying to solve, and ask how to solve that problem in language B.
This is similar to the XY Problem: you are trying to solve problem X. You think the way to solve problem X is solution Y. You run into a problem with Y. You ask for help with Y. People try to help you but are very confused because Y seems a strange problem to have in the first place. After many unsuccessful attempts and a lot of wasted time, you finally tell them about problem X, and it turns out that there is a really simple solution to X and even if you could have gotten Y to work, it wouldn't have solved the problem anyway.
Case in point: @dataclasses.dataclass is a decorator. Ruby doesn't have decorators. So, already right here, we run into the problem that there simply cannot be an equivalent.
So, let's forget about the decorator. Python class decorators are merely syntactic sugar for a function that takes a class as an argument and returns a class. But here we run into the next problem: Ruby doesn't have functions.
Okay, what about methods, then? Surely, we can have a method in Ruby which takes a class as an argument and returns a class. And, indeed we can. But, what the Python @dataclasses.dataclass decorator does is iterate over all attributes of the class and generate various functions based on those attributes. The closest equivalent to Python attributes are Ruby instance variables, but here's the final nail in the coffin: instance variables aren't declared at all in Ruby, they just magically spring into existence.
So, there is simply nothing for any method to iterate over. Implementing something like the @dataclasses.dataclass decorator is fundamentally impossible in Ruby.
Another thing the @dataclasses.dataclass decorator does is generate a friendly string representation which includes the name of the class. Classes in Ruby do not have a name, so that is not possible as well.
Roll your own
But there are other things you can do in Ruby. While it is not possible to iterate over the instance variables given only a class (simply because the instance variables are a property of the instance and not the class), it is certainly possible to generate a class given a list of instance variable names. Something like this:
module Kernel
  private

  def data_class(*instance_variables, superclass: Object)
    Class.new(superclass) do
      instance_variables.each(&method(:attr_accessor))

      define_method(:initialize) do |*args|
        instance_variables.zip(args).each do |instance_variable, arg|
          send("#{instance_variable}=", arg)
        end
      end

      define_method(:to_s) do
        class_name = self.class.name
        ivar_values = instance_variables.map do |instance_variable|
          "#{instance_variable}: #{send(instance_variable)}"
        end.join(', ')

        "#{class_name}(#{ivar_values})"
      end

      alias_method :inspect, :to_s
    end
  end
end

And you can use it like this:
MyDog = data_class(:fur_colour, :weight, :is_microchipped, :is_asleep)

my_dog = MyDog.new('tri-colour', 19.52, true, false)

Obviously, this leaves a lot to be desired in terms of usability and flexibility, but it proves the concept and it should not be too hard to extend this to be safer, more user-friendly, etc.
Struct
The Ruby core library contains two implementations of a similar idea.
The first is the Struct class. As the documentation says:

Class Struct provides a convenient way to create a simple class that can store and fetch values.

MyDog = Struct.new(:fur_colour, :weight, :is_microchipped, :is_asleep)

my_dog = MyDog.new('tri-colour', 19.52, true, false)

Data
The second is the Data class:

Class Data provides a convenient way to define simple classes for value-alike objects.

MyDog = Data.define(:fur_colour, :weight, :is_microchipped, :is_asleep)

my_dog = MyDog.new('tri-colour', 19.52, true, false)

Struct vs. Data
Having two different solutions immediately raises the question: so, what's the difference?
I see two major differences:

Struct acts much more like a mutable container, Data acts like an immutable record.
Data was added much later, so it has support for more modern features. For example, it automatically generates de-constructors for pattern matching, which did not exist when Struct was introduced.

